# iOS pass Generated XML with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift

```
 let stringParams : String = "<AddressValidateRequest USERID=\"252TEST01629\">" +
        "<Revision>1</Revision>" + "<Address ID=\"0\">" + "<Address1>SUITE K</Address1>"
        + "<Address2>29851 Aventura</Address2>" +
        "</City>"+"<State>CA</State>" + "<Zip5>92688</Zip5>" + "</Zip4>" + "</Address>" +
        "</AddressValidateRequest>"

        let url = URL(string:"http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=")
        var xmlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        xmlRequest.httpBody = stringParams.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        xmlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        xmlRequest.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


        self.alamoFireManager.request(xmlRequest)
            .responseData { (response) in
                let stringResponse: String = String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
                debugPrint(stringResponse)
        }
```

I am trying to send xml through Alamofire.
getting error say "XML Syntax Error: Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed"
any help will be appricated.thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like invalid xml, you can validate your xml string here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `Zip4` and `City` opening tag

It would be more clear to validate this xml by eye if you'll use multiline string as this:

```
let stringParams : String = """
    <AddressValidateRequest USERID="252TEST01629">
        <Revision>1</Revision>
        <Address ID="0">
            <Address1>SUITE K</Address1>
            <Address2>29851 Aventura</Address2>
            </City>
            <State>CA</State>
            <Zip5>92688</Zip5>
            </Zip4>
        </Address>
    </AddressValidateRequest>
    """
```

If you having troubles validating your xml by eye use [this](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0)
Also read [Swift documentation about multiline literals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID286)